# php include ruins page layout

Tags: php, css, require

I have a style problem with require or include function in php. Whenever I include a php file, even if this file is totally empty, all the page goes one line down which ruins the page order. I checked the source code after including the file and it seems that nothing is changed in the code. I am really confused, how is that possible. I hated this web stuff.

Here is some of the code. Problem is these includes at the top.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <?php
    include('database.php');
    include('login.php');
    ?>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Web Design - Free CSS Templates</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="free css templates, web design, 2-column, html css" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web Design is a 2-column website template (HTML/CSS) provided by templatemo.com" />
    <link href="templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--////// CHOOSE ONE OF THE 3 PIROBOX STYLES  \\\\\\\-->
    <link href="css_pirobox/white/style.css" media="screen" title="shadow" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--<link href="css_pirobox/white/style.css" media="screen" title="white" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css_pirobox/black/style.css" media="screen" title="black" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
    <!--////// END  \\\\\\\-->
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="templatemo_body_wrapper">
    <div id="templatemo_wrapper">

<div id="tempaltemo_header">
    <span id="header_icon"></span>
    <div id="header_content">
        <div id="site_title">
            <a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent"><img src="images/templatemo_logo.png" alt="LOGO" /></a>            </div>
        <p>This is a free CSS website layout from templatemo.com website.  Feel free to edit and apply for your websites. Duis vitae velit sed dui malesuad mollis aliquet ligula.</p>
      <a href="#" class="detail float_r">Detail</a>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of header -->
```

Template's source code seen by browser: http://www.text-upload.com/read,4081536104820

My edited code(nothing is edited except the include part): http://www.text-upload.com/read,4081542128884

Comment: Please show your source code. Then we'll be able to help.

Comment: Whats in `database.php` and `login.php` - any whitespace that is echo'd or HTML/blank lines that aren't wrapped in the PHP tags?

Comment: General complaining such as _"I hate this web stuff"_ and _"why downvote me?"_ usually only leads to more downvotes.  Also, as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), you're expected to be a professional or enthusiast programmer.

Comment: There is nothing in both files.

Comment: I didn't say I am not an enthusiast programmer but I am struggling with this problem for hours. Just got very bored with this little problem ruining all the page .

Comment: Can you post the source code as it is seen by the browser? That will likely show you what the problem is.

Comment: @mayy00 The source code you posted on text-upload is not the source code generated by the code above...

Comment: jeroen yeah it wasn't but part of it. Because when I delete the rest of the code the problem remained, I decided not to include all the code in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saving your files in UTF-8 with BOM, by any chance? Even an "empty" file in that encoding will have the Byte Order Mark, which will cause an empty space in your layout.

Either use a single-byte character set, or make sure you save as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. you saved me from hair loss :)